# How to call facts and rules from another file

Tags: prolog, ciao-prolog

Case: I have a file, solution.pl, where I want to use the rules of another file (this is the definition of the program, not up to me, but I think it's somewhat common).

So I'm using Ciao Prolog and the syntax seems to be `ensure_loaded('c:/Path').`

but when I try to use the rules of the other file, it tells me he doesn't know what rule I'm trying to use.

On the other hand, if I write on the console that same lane, and then query again, it does work.

So I was wondering maybe the syntax for doing it on the console and on a file are different??

Could someone tell me a step by step so I can figure it out if I'm missing something? What I'm doing right now is loading the program as I would do with smaller programs, then try to query rules of the file included in the `ensure_loaded` command. And as I said, it does seem to work if write the command outside of the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in solution.pl, try

```
:- ensure_loaded('c:/Path').
```

or, if the source in `c:/Path` has a module directive - that is, it begins with `:- module(name, [exported/arity, ...]).`

```
:- use_module('c:/Path').
```

Comment: I was missing the :- part. Like, I took it for granted, I thought it was like a prompt, duno why though. Thanks a lot, really frustrating knowing the code and not using it properly.